# Error whilst "numberOfLines"

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-instruction

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Error on following line: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"
        btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1;
        btn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        btn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

What should I do with this? Even my simulator won't open while this error occurs.

Comment: Your button outlet isn't connected.

Comment: You cannot set the UIButton to set number of lines , UILabel have this feature. I guess you can just set the wrap mode for teh UIButton and hence resolve the error.

Comment: @VickyDhas The code is trying to set `numberOfLines` on a `UILabel`. That's not the issue.